# Acceder a otra aplicación con C# windows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webforms

Actualmente me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto que controla un dispositivo motorizado dispensador de tarjetas. El dispositivo viene con una aplicación de escritorio básico (construido en lenguaje C). Necesitamos lograr que desde Visual Studio podamos interactuar con la interfaz de la aplicación de escritorio propio del dispositivo.

Necesito saber como lograrlo utilizando los forms

[image: Interfaz del dispositivo dispensador]

Comment: Deben haber mejores soluciones. Por ejemplo, si el programa admite uso desde consola puedes enviar comandos. En caso contrario, puedes encontrar algunas librerías que te permiten hacer lo que quieres. [Winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium) y [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver) son algunas.